# Getting Nodelist.length as zero when making a movie ticket app

Tags: javascript, html, css, event-listener

i am new to javascript and was making a new simple app that ...
when a user click on a seat. it will change from vacant to selected.
and in output, it shows the number of seats selected and total price.

but am not getting the total number of selected seats..its always showing  ,0   and in console...am getting nodelist.length as zero

here is that part of code

```
function update(){
    const selected=document.querySelectorAll('.row.seat.selected');
    const counts =selected.length;
    console.log(counts);
```

the sample html is;

```
<div class="row">
             <div class="seat"></div>
             <div class="seat"></div>
             <div class="seat"></div>
             <div class="seat"></div>
             <div class="seat"></div>
             <div class="seat"></div>
             <div class="seat"></div>
             <div class="seat"></div>
```

whenever  a click is done on seat..a new class of selected will attach

in this .row is class,,,in that another class of .seat...when user click on a seat,, a new class 'selected' will be added .

but am not getting the number of select seats to further codes...answer are really appreciated

Comment: Is `.seat` a child of `.row`? Then it should be `document.querySelectorAll('.row .seat.selected');`

Comment: Is `row` in the same element as `seat` and `selected`? Or is `seat` a child of `row`? in such case, the query should be something like `.row .seat.selected`.

Comment: i did the same there......row.seat.selected

Answer (score 0):

On click event on any Div a class "selected" is added to that Div, Your code should be like

```js
(function update(){
    const selected=document.querySelectorAll('.row .seat.selected');
    const counts =selected.length;
    console.log(counts);
    })()
```

```html
<div class="row">
             <div class="seat"></div>
             <div class="seat"></div>
             <div class="seat"></div>
             <div class="seat"></div>
             <div class="seat"></div>
             <div class="seat"></div>
             <div class="seat selected"></div>
             <div class="seat"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for the support..but actualy i need the total number of seats thats having a class "selected"......on a click on the seat....the ''slected 'class will be added as eventlistner

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the answers...problem solved    when i removed .row from that

that is

```
const selected=document.querySelectorAll('.row .seat.selected');
```

to

```
const selected=document.querySelectorAll('.seat.selected');
```

i dont know why..but now am getting correct